# NOTAM D item spanning across midnight with EXC

Tags: notam

The [specification of NOTAM](https://www.icao.int/NACC/Documents/eDOCS/AIM/8126_unedited_en%20Jul2021.pdf) is somewhat flaky. Edge cases may even be hard to parse programmatically unless [EUROCONTROL guidelines](https://www.eurocontrol.int/sites/default/files/2021-07/eurocontrol-guidelines-opadd-ed4-1.pdf) are being followed as well.

**For the sake of simplicity, let's assume the following examples are valid from 2022-01-01 thru 2022-01-31.**

D items (which specify the exact validity periods of the NOTAM) may span across midnight as follows:

```
D) 01-10 2100-0600
```

This is to be interpreted as follows:

> Valid for ten nights beginning with 2022-01-01 21:00 thru 2022-01-02 06:00 and ending with 2022-01-10 21:00 thru 2022-01-11.

So even though the dates mention only `01-10`, January 11 is also included as the times span across midnight. So far, so easy.

Things get hairy once exceptions are added to the mix:

```
D) 01-10 2100-0600 EXC WED
```

The only Wednesday in that period is on 2022-01-05. The above can be interpreted in two ways:

1. On **exactly** 2022-01-05, the times do not apply. So the NOTAM is not valid that Wednesday from midnight to 06:00 and from 21:00 to midnight.
2. The entire period **starting** 2022-01-05 is excluded. So the NOTAM is not valid that Wednesday from 21:00 thru the following Thursday 06:00.

I tend towards interpretation 2 since the other interpretation produces somewhat fragmented validities and I'm having a hard time imagining a situation where this actually makes sense.

But I can't find any hint about this case in the documentations. Has anybody seen such a case in the wild? Or maybe some more detailed official guide as of how to interpret such cases?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm a former Brazilian NOF (NOTAM Office) operator. The Brazilian regulation for NOTAM is [ICA 53-1](https://publicacoes.decea.mil.br/publicacao/ica-53-1) (click on **Download do arquivo**, open the downloaded PDF file and then see **Exemplo 9** at page **42/60**), which is compliant with ICAO's DOC 8126 (Chapter 6 - NOTAM) guidelines.

Based on DOC 8126 (Chapter 6) + ICA 53-1 + my experience as NOF operator, on the context described above, if I want to communicate circumstance #1 (i.e. the NOTAM is valid except on Wednesday 00:00 until 06:00 and 21:00 until 23:59), then I must type item D this way:

```
D) 01-10 2100-0600 EXC WED
```

(because `EXC WED` is a short for `EXC WED 0000-2359`, i.e. it's the **whole** Wednesday)

...or, alternatively:

```
D) 01-10 (EXC WED) 2100-0600
```

...even though the most appropriate way to express it more clearly (it's the one that I would use) is this:

```
D) 01-03 07-10 2100-0600 04 2100-2359 06 0000-0600 2100-0600
```

---

On the other hand, if I want to communicate circumstance #2 (i.e. the NOTAM is valid from Tuesday 21:00 until Wednesday 06:00 but not from Wednesday 21:00 until Thursday 06:00), then I must type item D this way:

```
D) 01-10 2100-0600 EXC WED/THU
```

...or, alternatively:

```
D) 01-10 (EXC WED/THU) 2100-0600
```

...even though the most appropriate way to express it more clearly (it's the one that I would use) is this:

```
D) 01-04 06-10 2100-0600
```

---

If I want the NOTAM to be valid except from Tuesday 21:00 until Thursday 06:00, then the item D becomes this:

```
D) 01-10 2100-0600 EXC TUE 2100 TIL THU 0600
```

...even though the most appropriate way to express it more clearly (it's the one that I would use) is this:

```
D) 01-03 06-10 2100-0600
```

---

**In a nutshell**:

- `WED` means the **whole** Wednesday, while `WED/THU` means "from Wednesday to Thursday"; and
- NOTAM operators are expected to use **number notation** instead of abbreviated week day names, precisely because of the confusion caused by these abbreviated names. Usage of abbreviated week day names is only justified when longer periods make number notation impracticable, e.g. `01-14 2100-0600 EXC WED` is preferable because number notation would require the text `01-03 07-10 14-15 2100-0600 04 11 2100-2359 06 13 0000-0600 2100-0600` even though the general rule of thumb is that NOTAMs must be short (but also clear i.e. easy to understand: they can't be dubious).

Comment: Thanks a lot for this extensive answer. Just a little followup: I've never actually sen the `WED/THU` notation. Single days of month are separated by spaces `1 5 8`, a range of days of month use the dash `5-7`. How come days of week use the slash instead? Is this documented somewhere?

Comment: @svoop You're welcome. I recall seeing `WED/THU`, but it's somewhat rare (precisely because number notation is overall preferred). Days of month are indeed separated by spaces, provided that they're not a range, as you mentioned, i.e. `01 03 05` is correct but not `01 02 03 04 05` (instead, the correct is `01-05`). The `/` (slash) indicates a change of day, thus `WED/THU` means the event starts one day, then the day changes but the event's still ongoing. I don't have access to ICAO's DOC 8126 anymore, but Brazil's ICA 53-1 features this example at page 42/60: `MON/TUE TIL FRI/SAT 2000-0400`.

Comment: DOC 8126 is available online here https://www.icao.int/NACC/Documents/eDOCS/AIM/8126_unedited_en%20Jul2021.pdf and NOTAM D-items are described on page III-6-14. But it's really minimalistic and doesn't say much about edge cases, also the `WED/THU` notation is not mentioned. (No surprise though, multiple schedules on one D-item are ignored as well why some NOTAM offices don't use commas to separate those as encouraged by EUROCONTROL as of https://www.eurocontrol.int/sites/default/files/2021-07/eurocontrol-guidelines-opadd-ed4-1.pdf

Comment: @svoop Thanks, I wasn't aware of Eurocontrol's mandatory guideline forbidding the use slash/oblique in Item D. Weirdly enough, ICAO's DOC 8126 is currently omissive about whether slash/oblique can be used or not. This is the likely reason why Eurocontrol forbids slash but not e.g. Brazil. For instance, see Brazil's international NOTAMs [O0501/22](https://aisweb.decea.mil.br/?i=notam&view=single&notam_id=8139727) and [I0925/22](https://aisweb.decea.mil.br/?i=notam&view=single&notam_id=8206953).

Comment: NOTAM really are an epic source of fun. 

Comment: @svoop Haha, true. 